# SQL using Case When statement with MAX and Partition Over in Where Clause

Tags: sql, max, case, partitioning

I have this query using a `case when` expression inside a `MAX()` aggregate function to obtain the maximum value of the case when statement.

However I need to filter also off that maximum value in the where clause. I can get the max date from the case when statement in my select clause but can't seem to understand how to filter off it in my where clause.

I know I could do a temp table and easily filter off that but I want to challenge myself and do it all in one.

This is my SQL statement - I want to get the latest status date for the ID, but I only want the one's with latest status date's >= 2022/01/01.

I know below doesn't work but I'm not sure what to do without putting this into a temp table.

```
SELECT 
    A1.ID, A1.STATUS, A1.DESCRIPTION,
    MAX(CASE 
            WHEN A1.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
                 AND A1.STATUS = 'C'
                THEN A1.STATUS_DATE
                ELSE NULL
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY A1.ID) AS LATEST_STATUS_DATE,
FROM 
    myTable A1
WHERE 
    MAX(CASE 
            WHEN A1.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
                    AND A1.STATUS = 'C'
                THEN A1.STATUS_DATE
                ELSE NULL
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY A1.ID) >= '20220101'
```

Comment: Please read; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.STATUS, A1.DESCRIPTION,

    MAX(CASE WHEN A1.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
                 AND A1.STATUS = 'C'
                 THEN A1.STATUS_DATE
             ELSE NULL
               END) AS LATEST_STATUS_DATE
                 
FROM myTable A1
GROUP BY A1.ID, A1.Status, A1.Description
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN A1.DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL
                 AND A1.STATUS = 'C'
                 THEN A1.STATUS_DATE
                 ELSE NULL
               END) >= '20220101'
```

Whether this actually works depends on the nature of the data, and whether `Status` and `Description` remain consistent in this table within a given `ID`.

Comment: So this gets me close. The only issue is the A1.STATUS_DATE in this table could have multiple dates for the status of 'C'. I tried doing the group by without the A1.STATUS_DATE but it kept yelling at me that it needs to be included in the group by. So unfortunately it returns multiple rows with same information.

Comment: @js468718 Oops, forgot to remove the window expression from SELECT clause. check it again with the updated code.

Comment: Awesome! This works! I actually found an alternative way yesterday, but your way is much cleaner. Thank you